# To check status of Tomcat server in Linux

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I need to know whether Tomcat 7.0.2.3 is on or not.

I got an error page that shows this message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /cas/login

type Status report

 message /cas/login

description The requested resource (/cas/login) is not available.
 Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
```

I need to check the status and start the service of Tomcat in Linux. I have tried:

```
#/bin/startup.sh
#rctomcat7 start
```

But all these are not working.

Comment: It's on, or you wouldn't have gotten the 404 message.

Comment: Ditto Paul. But if you did want to how to check / restart we'd need to know how you've set it up: as a service in /etc/init.d, or something else? How did you install it - as a package from your distro or from the source yourself, or something else? Which distro?

Answer (score 1):

Like others have pointed out, if you are receiving an [HTTP standard response code of 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) then it means that Tomcat is up.

But to answer your question, you can try

```
 #rctomcat7 status
```

Comment: I have Ubuntu 13/04, Tomcat 8 extracted as zip (first download) to my home folder.

I do not have a init.d script, neither your idea Kevin is working. I start and stop with catalina.sh which works. But how check status?

Comment: Just install it from a package with proper init script. If you don’t have Tomcat package in your distro, then try to find any third-part init script or write your own. It’s not so hard. The scripts distributed with Tomcat aren’t good for production.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below script. This script check tomcat post and process is running up or not,if not then start the tomcat.

Tomcat Start script

```
if netstat -tulpen | grep 18880 && ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep java

then

    echo "Tomcat Running"

else

    echo "Tomcat Stopped"

    /bin/sh /tomcat/bin/startup.sh

fi
```

Comment: to create and run the above mentioned script. I executed - $ mkdir script
$ cd script/ $ vi check_if_tomcat_is_running.sh $ chmod +x check_if_tomcat_is_running.sh $ ./check_if_tomcat_is_running.sh